# Meta Viewport tag not scaling page

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-safari

I'm developing a page for iPad visitors, but the the meta viewport tag doesn't seem to be working. I'm using the following tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The page in question is here: http://www.ixl.com/files/quia/users/landing_pgs/ipad_ret/page.html.

I've tried many permutations of the viewport meta tag, but none seem to do the trick. Safari keeps rendering the page much wider than the viewport.

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A viewport is not the only thing needed to make websites scale to the device viewed on. You need to look into media queries. You will generally have a couple of media queries, ie: mobile and a tablet version. In the media queries you will only change the coding for the necessary things that need changes. So if you are looking to only fit the sizing of your page, only change the sizing in your media queries. There's a lot on here about media queries, check it out.

Adding on:

You would format it somewhat like this:

```
"large" css here

 @media only screen and (max-width:800px)
 {
"medium" css changes here
}

 @media only screen and (max-width:480px)
{
"small" css changes here
}
```

Comment: I've been reading up on media queries, but I can't seem to find anything that scales the page to 100% of the browser screen at load time.  Isn't that what the meta viewport tag is for?  It seems like media queries are more for making CSS adjustment between versions of the page based on screen size?

Comment: Are you looking for a desktop like version to display on tablets?

Comment: They way I'm using this page, only people on iPads will ever see it, so the presentation on desktop is not important.